# Sum of count of records from different tables group by records' created date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I have six tables from which I am fetching a number of rows grouped by their created date.

For example :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS NoOfReading FROM TableA
WHERE IsDeleted = 0 
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CreatedDtUTC,111)

SELECT COUNT(*) AS NoOfReading FROM TableB
WHERE IsDeleted = 0 
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CreatedDtUTC,111)

SELECT COUNT(*) AS NoOfReading FROM TableC
WHERE IsDeleted = 0 
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CreatedDtUTC,111)
```

and onwards..

Now I want to make `sum of NoOfReading` from all of the tables group by created date. Any solution??

P.S. : I have tried using "+" between all of the queries but giving error.

Thanks

Comment: So you have 6 identical tables structure-wise? Sounds like it's calling for unions

Comment: @Scotch - 6 identical tables says to me that it ought to be one table with an additional column containing whatever the distinguishing feature is that currently decides which identical table it goes into.

Comment: I think union will remove the records that are of same values. I want to make sum of number of records by date, and the records are in different tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple addition can work..

```
select (
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableA
    WHERE IsDeleted = 0 
    GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CreatedDtUTC,111))
    +
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableB
    WHERE IsDeleted = 0 
    GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CreatedDtUTC,111))
    +
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableC
    WHERE IsDeleted = 0 
    GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CreatedDtUTC,111))
    )  AS NoOfReadingSum
```

Comment: Error : Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. I think I found the solution using union all and then make sum. What do you think?

Comment: Hey.. It's OK.. I am happy because you people helped me. Thanks alot..:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL` which preserves duplicates:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS NoOfReading FROM
(
   SELECT CreatedDtUTC,IsDeleted FROM TableA
   UNION ALL
   SELECT CreatedDtUTC,IsDeleted FROM TableB
   UNION ALL
   SELECT CreatedDtUTC,IsDeleted FROM TableC
) t
WHERE IsDeleted = 0 
GROUP BY DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,CreatedDtUTC),0)
```

Comment: Error : Invalid column name 'IsDeleted'. IsDeleted is not exists in all of the tables.

Comment: @Dev - yes, I realised about a minute ago that I needed to include that column also. I don't have your data available, so I can't test the query.

Comment: Ya.. Sorry for not providing the details exactly.. and thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it my self :

```
;WITH MeasurementReadings(NoOfReading, CreatedDtUTC) AS 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS  NoOfReading, CreatedDtUTC FROM TableA
    WHERE IsDeleted = 0 
    GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CreatedDtUTC,111)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS  NoOfReading, CreatedDtUTC  FROM TableB
    WHERE IsDeleted = 0 
    GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CreatedDtUTC,111)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS  NoOfReading, CreatedDtUTC FROM TableC
    WHERE IsDeleted = 0 
    GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CreatedDtUTC,111)
)  
SELECT SUM(NoOfReading) AS NoOfRecords, CreatedDtUTC 
FROM MeasurementReadings
GROUP BY CreatedDtUTC
```

Thanks